# LISP: How to use strings in defparameters

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am a beginner in Lisp. I have two `functions`, a `defparameter`, and a `defstruct`. Every time a book is passed to `inputBook` I would like the title of the book (the string) to become the name of the `defparameter`. Is this possible?
I have tried to hard code a string in like below where it says "MobyDick" but I get an error. So is this even possible?

I tried to simply use the parameter passed `title` but if you try to pass another book into the function, they are *both* assigned to `title` but the last one passed will print, not the first and not both. So how can I do it so that I have as many "books" without a list or a hash table?

If the latter is not possible, how could I alter the code so that a `defparameter` would be created (unique) to any number of books and accessible through the `getAuthor` function? Does that make sense? (Please see the functions below.)

```
(defstruct book()
    (title) ;;title of the book, type string
    (author) ;;author of the book, type string
    (date))  ;; date of the book, type string or int

(defun inputBook(title author month year)
    (defparameter "MobyDick" ;;I want this to use the parameter title
        (make-book :title title
                   :author author
                   :date '(month year))))

(defun getAuthor (book)
    (write (book-author book)))
```

Many many thanks in advance! Also, I am a beginner beginner. I have been learning through googling and I am stumped here.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Why are you using `defparameter` at all?

Comment: I am using defparameter to create a global variable so I can access the book created in inputBook in getAuthor. I tried doing it without defparameter and just used setq make-book but when I got to getAuthor the book did not exist.

Comment: That makes no sense. How are you using your functions?

Comment: Okay. So essentially I want the user to pass in a book to inputBook using all four parameters. Then I want to create that book using the defstruct. So I am using make-book to do that. I am using the defparameter so I can access the book that was just made using make-book in getAuthor. if I don't use defparameter, then the function getAuthor will not be able to get the author of the book. Makes sense? I'm sorry if I'm not explaining this very well. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: What is not clear for me is if you want to create a single book, and assign it to a global (special in CL jargon) variable, or want to assign it to a special variable with the same name as the title of the book, of if you want to create multiple books, and assign each of them to a different special variables called as the title of the book, or what else?

Comment: @Renzo I want to create multiple books and assign each of them to a different special variable called as the title of the book. So every time I book is added I would like to create a special variable with the same name as the title of the book.

Comment: @BensSteves That's terrible design.  If you want a namespace for books, *make a namespace for books*, don't reuse the namespace of top-level variables.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want something which looks like this, rather than some madness of top-level variables.

```
(defvar *books* (make-hash-table))

(defun bookp (title)
  (nth-value 1 (gethash title *books*)))

(defun remove-book (title)
  (remhash title *books*))

(defun book (title)
  (nth-value 0 (gethash title *books*)))

(defun (setf book) (new title)
  (setf (gethash title *books*) new))
```

Then, for instance:

```
> (setf (book 'moby) (make-book ...))
> (book 'moby)
> (bookp 'moby)
> (remove-book 'moby)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using symbols with arbitrary names has the typical drawback: you can overwrite the values of existing symbols. Thus it would be useful to have a separate package for it, which does not import symbols from other packages.

Better would be to have a hash table, which would map from a string to the book object.

Sketch of code with symbols:

```
(defstruct book
  (title)  ;; title of the book,  type string
  (author) ;; author of the book, type string
  (date))  ;; date of the book,   type list

(defun input-book (title author month year)
  (setf (symbol-value (intern title))
        (make-book :title title
                   :author author
                   :date (list month year))))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 52 > (input-book "Lisp Style & Design"
                         "Molly M. Miller, Eric Benson"
                         1 1990)
#S(BOOK :TITLE "Lisp Style & Design"
        :AUTHOR "Molly M. Miller, Eric Benson"
        :DATE (1 1990))

CL-USER 53 > (book-author (symbol-value '|Lisp Style & Design|))
"Molly M. Miller, Eric Benson"

CL-USER 54 > (book-author |Lisp Style & Design|)
"Molly M. Miller, Eric Benson"
```